# XSLT to insert element with part of XPath as value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to move some elements around and to create an child in each of them indicating where they came from in the original XML.

Here is a subset of the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SAN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CiscoCollection/>
    <EQLHosts>
        <LinuxHosts>
            <LinuxHost>
                <Server>
                    <HostName>rhel6mgt</HostName>
                </Server>
            </LinuxHost>
        </LinuxHosts>
        <WindowsHosts/>
        <WindowsClusters/>
        <VMwareHosts/>
    </EQLHosts>
    <CompellentHosts>
        <LinuxHosts/>
        <WindowsHosts>
            <WindowsHost>
                <Server>
                    <HostName>R1-Lasso-2</HostName>
                </Server>
            </WindowsHost>
        </WindowsHosts>
        <WindowsClusters/>
        <VMwareHosts/>
    </CompellentHosts>
    <HostCollection>
        <LinuxHosts>
            <LinuxHost>
                <Server>
                    <HostName>rhel7mgt</HostName>
                </Server>
            </LinuxHost>
        </LinuxHosts>
        <WindowsHosts>
            <WindowsHost>
                <Server>
                    <HostName>R1-Lasso-1</HostName>
                </Server>
            </WindowsHost>
        </WindowsHosts>
        <WindowsClusters>
            <Cluster>
                <ClusterNodes>
                    <WindowsHost>
                        <Server>
                            <HostName>R1-Lasso-3</HostName>
                        </Server>
                    </WindowsHost>
                </ClusterNodes>
            </Cluster>
        </WindowsClusters>
        <VMwareHosts>
            <VMwareHost>
                <Server>
                    <HostName>Rack9-ESXi5.1</HostName>
                </Server>
            </VMwareHost>
        </VMwareHosts>
    </HostCollection>
</SAN>
```

My existing XSLT file correctly moves the data to a single tree "Hosts":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-03-16T10:53:27">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SAN">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(name()='EQLHosts' or
                                                  name()='CompellentHosts' or
                                                  name()='MDSeriesHosts' or
                                                  name()='HostCollection')]"/>
            <Hosts>
                <WindowsHosts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsHosts/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/VirtualMachines/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/CompellentHosts/WindowsHosts/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/CompellentHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/CompellentHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/VirtualMachines/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/HostCollection/WindowsHosts/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/HostCollection/WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/HostCollection/WindowsClusters/Cluster/VirtualMachines/WindowsHost"/>
                </WindowsHosts>
                <VMwareHosts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/EQLHosts/VMwareHosts/VMwareHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/CompellentHosts/VMwareHosts/VMwareHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/MDSeriesHosts/VMwareHosts/VMwareHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/HostCollection/VMwareHosts/VMwareHost"/>
                </VMwareHosts>
                <LinuxHosts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/EQLHosts/LinuxHosts/LinuxHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/CompellentHosts/LinuxHosts/LinuxHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/MDSeriesHosts/LinuxHosts/LinuxHost"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SAN/HostCollection/LinuxHosts/LinuxHost"/>
                </LinuxHosts>
            </Hosts>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I want to add the value "EQLHosts" or "CompellentHosts" or "HostCollection" to an element under each "xxxHost", like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SAN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <CiscoCollection/>
   <Hosts xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-03-16T10:53:27">
      <WindowsHosts>
         <WindowsHost>
            <Server>
               <HostName>R1-Lasso-2</HostName>
               <MyNewElement>CompellentHosts</MyNewElement>
            </Server>
         </WindowsHost>
         <WindowsHost>
            <Server>
               <HostName>R1-Lasso-1</HostName>
               <MyNewElement>HostCollection</MyNewElement>
            </Server>
         </WindowsHost>
         <WindowsHost>
            <Server>
               <HostName>R1-Lasso-3</HostName>
               <MyNewElement>HostCollection</MyNewElement>
            </Server>
         </WindowsHost>
      </WindowsHosts>
      <VMwareHosts>
         <VMwareHost>
            <Server>
               <HostName>Rack9-ESXi5.1</HostName>
               <MyNewElement>HostCollection</MyNewElement>
            </Server>
         </VMwareHost>
      </VMwareHosts>
      <LinuxHosts>
         <LinuxHost>
            <Server>
               <HostName>rhel6mgt</HostName>
               <MyNewElement>EQLHosts</MyNewElement>
            </Server>
         </LinuxHost>
         <LinuxHost>
            <Server>
               <HostName>rhel7mgt</HostName>
               <MyNewElement>HostCollection</MyNewElement>
            </Server>
         </LinuxHost>
      </LinuxHosts>
   </Hosts>
</SAN>
```

Can I do this easily in this same XSLT file?

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with your XSLT. Just create a template that matches the **Server** element, like so,

```
<xsl:template match="Server">
```

And in it, add the **xsl:copy** to copy the element, in a similar manner to the identity template, but also add the following code to output the new element

```
 <MyNewElement><xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::*[parent::SAN])" /></MyNewElement>
```

In this case, it is finding the name of the ancestor element, that is the direct child of the **SAN** element.

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-03-16T10:53:27">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SAN">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(name()='EQLHosts' or
                                                  name()='CompellentHosts' or
                                                  name()='MDSeriesHosts' or
                                                  name()='HostCollection')]"/>
            <Hosts>
                <WindowsHosts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//WindowsHost"/>
                </WindowsHosts>
                <VMwareHosts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//VMwareHost"/>
                </VMwareHosts>
                <LinuxHosts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//LinuxHost"/>
                </LinuxHosts>
            </Hosts>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Server">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <MyNewElement><xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::*[parent::SAN])" /></MyNewElement>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have also simplified the code to get the various **...Host** elements which may or may not be helpful to you....

Comment: Perfect!

I couldn't get the right combination of code to get this to work.  Your solution works like a champ, with the extra bonus of shortening all the absolute XPath specifications that are now replaced by the simple .// syntax.

Thank you!